# Accessing domainIdentifier from NSUserActivity with Spotlight

Tags: ios, swift, corespotlight, nsuseractivity

I'm indexing 'Person' and 'Product' objects into Spotlight like so:

```
// Person
let personItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: personID, domainIdentifier: "person", attributeSet: attributeSet)                

CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems([personItem]) { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print("Indexing error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("person added to spotlight")
    }
}


// Product
let productItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: productID, domainIdentifier: "product", attributeSet: attributeSet)                

CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems([productItem]) { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print("Indexing error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("product added to spotlight")
    }
}
```

You can see that I'm using to `domainIdentifier`s: "person" & "product". But how would I access these `domainIdentifier`s when I come back into the app?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType {

        // if product do this
        // if person do that

    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, in `CoreSpotlight` you don't have direct access to `domainIdentifier`. What you have is `uniqueIdentifier`, so you can work around it with some prefix in it of some sort. To get the identifier you can use:

```
if let itemActivityIdentifier = userActivity.userInfo?["kCSSearchableItemActivityIdentifier"] {

}
```

in your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: thanks. each `Product` or `Person` has an associated website URL - i.e. example.com/person/1234 example.com/product/1234. So it might make sense for me to use the url string as a uniqueIdentifier, as then parse it in `continueUserActivity`.

Comment: Maybe not the whole URL, but product/1234, person/1234 seems like an idea, easy to parse.